# Do changes made by npm audit fix persist after pushing the code to git repo?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-audit

I recently discovered the `npm audit` feature and ran the command to find vulnerabilities in a project I'm working on. Came across a bunch of them (over 100).

`npm` suggests that running `npm audit fix` will fix all vulnerabilities except those which have breaking changes. I didn't encounter any such vulnerability in my code and now it shows 0 vulnerabilities.

My question is that when I push the code to github will these vulnerabilities be fixed already for someone who clones/forks this repo?

For context, `node_modules` are ignored in my `.gitignore` file (Which means they are not pushed to github along with the code). Since `node_modules` is where these "vulnerability fixes" are applied, do they persist for everyone who then forks/clones this repo?

If so, how? Does it have something to do with `package-lock.json`?

If not, is there a way to make these changes persistent?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it has to do with the `package-lock.json`, [read more about package-locks here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks)
According to the site currently, the package-lock represents a reproducible tree of your node_modules folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, changes made by `npm audit fix` are persistent, but only if you commit your `package-lock.json` file to your git repository.

[According to NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.html), "this file is intended to be committed into source repositories."

If you commit your existing `package-lock.json` file to your repository and then run `npm audit fix`, you will see changes to your local `package-lock.json` file (assuming `npm audit` was able to fix any vulnerable packages). You can review these changes and then commit the `package-lock.json` file a second time to persist the changes.